# Coordinates of the segments of the hair particle

Tags: python, scripting, particles, coordinates

All Hair Particles are based on Vertices. I activated the option in ParticleSystem "Advanced" and switched to Verts. A hair has 4 segments. I would like to read these segments per hair as coordinates. How does that look in Python?

Answer (score 0):

what is your level in Python? I mean are you able to reproduce code from Blender if this need?
I could share with you an approach for this, but more like workaround instead of direct solution,... because I can't understand the main purpose of your question.

What I understood, is that you want to control a particle hair system resolution, emitted trough vertices ...

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Or you can only use the Sphere to control, removing  the previous script note property.

[image]

Hope this will help you!